# Device is not searching any new endpoints in Nearby API

Tags: android, google-nearby

There is some weird thing happening, when a device has been running advert/discovery API for a long time(15-20 mins). it stops discovering new endpoints. Though discovery/advertising is on but it will not search new device or will be shown in some other devices discovery. What can be possible reasons for that and how can we get out of this state. Currently only things that work is restarting the device, or close the app and launch after 10-15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying each of these steps (individually, one at a time):

a) Stop and restart discovery.

b) Stop and restart advertising.

c) Toggle the Bluetooth radio on/off once. Restart advertising + discovery afterwards.

Let me know which ones resolve the issues and which don't.